# How do I extract a key with jq based on its child values

Tags: jq

I'm trying to process some JSON with jq.  Specifically, I want a particular key, based on its child value.  Example, given:

```
{
  "foo": {"primary": true, "blah": "beep"},
  "bar": {"primary": false, "blah": "narf"},
  "baz": {"primary": false, "blah": "poink"},
}
```

I want the string "foo", because that is the key whose child value "primary' is true.  (I can guarantee that one and only one entry will have primary = true, due to what's generating the JSON.)

So far the best I've been able to manage is:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.primary == true)'
```

But that returns the value of "foo", not the string "foo" itself.  Digging through the manual so far I've not found a way to grab the key specifically.

Any pointers you can provide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to "split" your object into an array of entries, e.g.

```
[
  {
    "key": "foo",
    "value": {
      "primary": true,
      "blah": "beep"
    }
  }
  //...
]
```

Then you can filter with `.value.primary` and map the result with `.key`:

```jq
to_entries | map(select(.value.primary)  | .key)
```

Returns:

```
[
  "foo"
]
```

Or to get just the first item of the array: (Thanks @nbari)

```jq
to_entries | map(select(.value.primary)  | .key)[0]
```

Comment: `input | jq -r 'to_entries | map(select(.value.primary == true) | .key)[0]'` to just get `foo`

Comment: The `== true` isn't necessary; as `foo == true` has the same truth value as `foo` itself for any boolean-valued `foo`.

Comment: Thanks both. I incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: Ah, to_entries is just what I needed.  That worked perfectly.  Many thanks!